# wes 7 cd\dvd boot

Tags: windows

I am new to wes 7 I haven worked with any  embedded  technology before. I'm trying to do a poc form my firm of wes7 and I need to make a bootable cd\dvd since we need a stateless system.

This is a crucial point of go\no go with wes7.

I understand there is no support for cd\dvd boot in wes7 but I can use winpe.

Do I still go on learning wes 7 or should I change direction and go to winpe?

If you can directe me to any good tutorial/help for me with winPE  it will be a great help.

I bougt a book on wes 7 but I'm not sure I continue with it

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain what "wes" is and all of your other acronyms? I have no idea what you're asking here; please edit to make it more clear what you're trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Very complicated to understand what you want.

Personally, unless you have a specific reason to use embedded Windows, I would take a look at using a bog standard Windows installation in combination with state management. They no longer off an all in one tool, however Technet has an [excellent article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg176676%28WS.10%29.aspx)  which should point you in the right direction to setting this up.

Alternatively, you can use a commercial product such as [Norton Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/) or [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/DeepFreezeCorporate.aspx)

As for WinPE, it entirely depends on what the machine will be used for. I would recommend against WinPE for pretty much anything non maintenance. Remember, it is highly restricted and a number of features will not work from it.